# Deactivate auto gzip decompress

Tags: python, locust

Using Locust `FastHTTPUser`, is it possible to prevent automatic gzip decompression ? I need to spare some CPU usage.

Comment: As far as I know it will decompress trying to find response-length even if you don't access the content. Fasthttpuser uses geventhttpclient under the hood so you might be able to disable decompression if you modify that library locally.